Confusion about logical jump in proof relating to points on conic and cross ratio
Let $p$ and $q$ be two distinct points in $\mathbb{RP}^2$. Let $ L_p $ and $ L_q $ be the sets of all lines that pass through $ p $ and $ q $, respectively. Let $ \tau : L_p \to L_q $ be a projective transformation that is not a perspectivity. Then the points
$
\text{meet}(l, \tau(l))
$
are all points of a certain conic $ C $.
$\textbf{Proof.}$ Let $ l_1, l_2, l_3, l_4 $ be four arbitrary lines from $ L_p $ not through $ q $. Consider the points $ a_i = \text{meet}(l_i, \tau(l_i)) $, for $ i = 1, \ldots, 4 $. Since the two bundles of lines are related by a projective transformation, the cross-ratio $(l_1, l_2; l_3, l_4) $ equals the cross-ratio $ (\tau(l_1), \tau(l_2); \tau(l_3), \tau(l_4)) $. This relation can be written as
$
(a_1, a_2; a_3, a_4)_p = (a_1, a_2; a_3, a_4)_q.
$
The proof then continues but I don't see how "this relation can be written as". I dont know why $
(a_1, a_2; a_3, a_4)_p = (a_1, a_2; a_3, a_4)_q.
$
Can anyone explain it please?
Source "Perspectives in Projective Geometry"
Thank you

It's not clear what your stumbling block is, but I assume it's because you don't know what $(a_1, a_2; a_3, a_4)_p$ means.
For points $w,x,y,z,p$, the expression $(w,x;y,z)_p$ denotes the cross ratio of the lines $wp,xp,yp,zp$.  This notation is defined on pg. 171 of the book.
If that's not enough to get you to the finish line, let me know and I'll elaborate further.
Update: For points $o,a,c$ let $\mathbf a=a-o$ and $\mathbf c=c-o$, and $\alpha=$the angle between $\mathbf a$ and $\mathbf c$.  Then $[o,a,c]=\mathbf a \times \mathbf c= \|a\|\|c\|\sin(\alpha)$.  This can be used to show that the book's definition of line cross-ratio is equivalent to the traditional line cross-ratio using sine of angles.

Thanks for your answer, it really clarified a bit. I am now wondering how do I interpret "the cross ratio of lines"? I've tried converting it into its duel form but I can't see how the cross ratio expression given on p.171 represents the cross ratios of these lines/points.

Do you think you could explain how the expression [p,1,3][p,2,4]/... corresponds to the cross ratio of the lines p1,p2...?

Good question, but that's a bigger topic than I have time for right now.  Try finding the paper "The Cross Ratio Is the Ratio of Cross Products!" on jstor.org.  If that doesn't help, please open a new separate question.

Thanks for your help, I was going in cross product loops so it will be intriguing to see an article on this

Great!  Perhaps you've noticed that cross products are a little like determinants, so this paper may help you see the bridge from the traditional $\sin(\angle)$ based definition of cross ratios of lines to the determinant based definition used in this book.

So, the cross ratio can be considered the ratio of triangle areas (determinants). Hence, choosing a suitable definition for the cross ratio of lines, we can get an equivalence between the cross ratio of lines and points. However, I find it concerning that the author left the definition for cross ratios of lines out of the book.

A cross-ratio for lines is defined on pg 77, but it is sort of incidental.  The reader can be forgiven for having forgotten about it (and Lemma 4.6) when the concept is mentioned again on pg. 171.

It was a different definition than the one in the article. Where they define the cross ratio of lines as a ratio of the sine of angles between the lines, briefly how is this equivalent to the definition of page 77, I can't figure it out?

I've added an update that hopefully clarifies your issue.
